# question about keras.losses.mean_square_error

Tags: python, keras

When checking the code of keras loss, I find out the loss of mean square error is defined as below:

```
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

But, when the y_true is 4D tensor with shape of (n,h,w,c), this function seems return a 3D tensor result and it should raise an error.

However when training, the function still works fine. What happened when I training a neural network when using this function.

Thanks for your answering

Comment: A 3D tensor is only returned because mean is being calculated on the last dimension. If I have a 2D Tensor like `[ [ 2 , 3 ] ]` then carrying out mean operation in the 2nd dimension will result in `[ 2.5 ]` which 1D Tensor.

Comment: Yes, but when your print the loss when training, you will find out the loss is a scalar not a tensor. It seems when calculating the loss, if the loss is more than 1D tensor, the keras will take the sum of them as the true loss used for feedback.